# multiple errors in using with function in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm having some problems with my select statement. When I try to execute it, it gives 3 errors

Must specify table to select from
An object or column name is missing or empty for SELECT INFO statements. verify each column

has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined...

Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

```
WITH A AS
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
                CASE
                    WHEN @pOrderBy = 'SortByName' THEN colPortAgentVendorNameVarchar
                    WHEN @pOrderBy = 'SortByCOuntry' THEN colCountryNameVarchar
                    WHEN @pOrderBy = 'SortByCity' THEN colCityNameVarchar
                END, 
                colPortAgentVendorNameVarchar
            ) xRow, A.*
            FROM
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                    V.colPortAgentVendorIDInt,
                    colPortAgentVendorNameVarchar = RTRIM(LTRIM(V.colPortAgentVendorNameVarchar)),
                    C.colCountryNameVarchar,
                    Y.colCityNameVarchar,
                    V.colContactNoVarchar,
                    V.colFaxNoVarchar,
                    V.colEmailToVarchar,
                    V.colWebsiteVarchar,
                    BR.colBrandIdInt,
                    PR.colPriorityTinyint,
                    colBrandCodeVarchar = RTRIM(LTRIM(BR.colBrandCodeVarchar))

                FROM dbo.TblVendorPortAgent  V
                LEFT JOIN TblCountry C ON C.colCountryIDInt = V.colCountryIDInt
                LEFT JOIN TblCity Y ON Y.colCityIDInt = V.colCityIDInt          
                LEFT JOIN tblBrandAirportPortAgent PR ON PR.colPortAgentVendorIDInt = V.colPortAgentVendorIDInt
                    AND PR.colIsActiveBit = 1
                LEFT JOIN TblBrand BR ON BR.colBrandIdInt = PR.colBrandIdInt
                    AND BR.colIsActiveBit = 1
                WHERE V.colIsActiveBit = 1
                AND V.colPortAgentVendorNameVarchar LIKE '%'+ @pPortAgentVendor +'%'            
                AND (PR.colBrandIdInt = @pBrandID OR @pBrandID = 0)
            ) A

        )
        INSERT INTO #tempPortAgent

        SELECT A.*, IsWithContract = CASE WHEN colContractIdInt IS NULL THEN CAST(0 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT)  END FROM A LEFT JOIN TblContractPortAgent B ON A.colPortAgentVendorIDInt = B.colPortAgentVendorIDInt
                AND B.colIsActiveBit = 1
        ;WITH QQ AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Q.colPortAgentVendorIDInt ORDER BY xRow, 
            ContractStatusOrder,
            colDateCreatedDate DESC
            )ContractRow,*
        FROM
        (       
            SELECT DISTINCT GG.*, B.colContractIdInt, B.colContractStatusVarchar, B.colDateCreatedDate , 
                ContractStatusOrder = CASE WHEN B.colContractStatusVarchar = 'Approved' THEN 1 ELSE '2' END
            FROM #tempPortAgent GG LEFT JOIN TblContractPortAgent B ON GG.colPortAgentVendorIDInt = B.colPortAgentVendorIDInt
                AND B.colIsActiveBit = 1
        ) Q
    )SELECT * INTO #tempPortAgentWithContract   

    SELECT * FROM #tempPortAgentWithContract
```

I don't really know where its showing, because the errors are saying that these are inside the select statements inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Use `Select Into` instead of `Insert into select`

```
SELECT A.*, IsWithContract = CASE WHEN colContractIdInt IS NULL THEN CAST(0 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT)  END 
Into #tempPortAgent
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN TblContractPortAgent B ON A.colPortAgentVendorIDInt = B.colPortAgentVendorIDInt
                AND B.colIsActiveBit = 1
```

2- `SELECT * INTO #tempPortAgentWithContract` is incorrect syntax. you must use following format:

```
SELECT * INTO #tempPortAgentWithContract From QQ
```

Comment: I just tried it, and it says "there is alreayd an object named #tempPortAgent in the database", is there something I still need to do to make it work?

Comment: because #tempPortAgent created on your session. you can drop #tempPortAgent first if exists, or can execute your query in new query window in order to have new session.